# Connect to a DBIx::Class database without repeating the connection details?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

[`DBIx::Class::Manual::Intro`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Intro.pod)
suggests connecting to the database as follows

```
my $schema = MyApp::Schema->connect(...)
```

explicitly providing connection details such as the password.

I want to connect to the same database from multiple different scripts, and it would be unwise to code the same connection parameters into each of the programs separately.

What is the "official" way to create a connection method with fixed connection details?

I realize that I can write something like this

```
package MyApp::Schema;

use base qw/DBIx::Class::Schema/;

sub my_connect {
  $_[0]::SUPER->connect(...);
}

1;
```

Is this approach recommended?

I realize that providing different connection details may be useful for testing scripts, but in reality we do not yet use testing scripts, so this is currently irrelevant for our team.

Answer (score 0):

Put your connection details in a config file, create a utility to return the connection and read the config details like you showed, or as a factory type function. Make the config dependant on the environment and you'll have testing capabilities for free.

Comment: This answer is a stub. Feel free to expand it.